# Groovy @CompileStatic @CompileDynamic going bananza. Bug?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import groovy.transform.CompileDynamic
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
@Transactional
abstract class BaseService<T> implements DefaultDomainServiceMethods<T> {
    DBService DBService

    @CompileDynamic
    boolean isNew(def domainInstance) {
        return !domainInstance.id
    }

}
```

Results in the following error on grails run-app

```
|Compiling 1 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
/samson/projects/samsongit/grails/samsonmain/grails-app/services/samson/BaseService.groovy: 14: [Static type checking] - No such property: id for class: java.lang.Object
 @ line 14, column 17.
           return !domainInstance.id
                   ^

1 error
```

Obviously the @CompileDynamic is not working. When changing this after grails run-app has run, the console get stackoverflowed in a loop of error messages.

Intellij does not report any errors.

Comment: I apologize for the erroneous answer I just posted.  As soon as I submitted it I realized that I had misread the original code and deleted the incorrect answer right away.  I don't think it was there long enough to mislead anyone but if it did, my apologies.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Sorry Scott, I missed it, I wish I didnt. I am sure there were some useful insights :)